# How to use route parameter using controller

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, routes, controller

What am i trying to do is making my URL can be accesed like this : localhost/information/{grade}/{class}. If i'm using **route directly to view**, i can do it like this :

```
Route::get('information/{grade}/{class}', function ($grade, $class) {
$data = [$grade, $class];
return view('information')->with('data', $data);
})->name('info');
```

but, instead of doing like that, i'm trying to use it like this : **route -> controller -> view**. Here is my code so far :

web.php :

```
Route::get('information/{grade}/{class}',[InformasiController::class,'index']);
```

The controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class InformasiController extends Controller
{
    public function index($grade, $class)
    {
        $data = [$grade, $class];
        return view('information')->with('data', $data);
    }
}
```

But, i get error like this :

[click to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbEK1.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need to update this line

```
$data = [$grade, $class];
```

to

```
$data = ['grade'=>$grade,'class'=> $class];
```

Comment: Thank you, just try it and it works.